# How can I expand with brackets but use commas instead of spaces as the separators in the output?

Tags: bash-expansion

I need to do `IFS=",";echo {1..5}` so that it can output `1,2,3,4,5` instead of `1 2 3 4 5`. How do I make bash echo {1..5} and output the values with a comma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Bash's builtins:

This is a bit ugly since we need to separate the `5` to avoid a trailing comma:

```
$ printf '%s,' {1..4}; echo 5
1,2,3,4,5
```

Though since `printf` can output directly to a variable, that can be worked around and the final comma removed with a parameter expansion:

```
$ printf -v tmpvar "%s," {1..5}; echo "${tmpvar%,}"
1,2,3,4,5
```

Or with `"$*"`, which joins using the first character of `IFS`. This trashes global state, but you could rather easily avoid that by running it in a subshell or in a function with `local IFS`:

```
$ IFS=,; set -- {1..5}; echo "$*";
1,2,3,4,5
```

If the limits are in variables, it's probably easiest to just do it manually with a loop since you can't use variables as endpoints in a brace expansion range. Again, the upper limit is in a special case:

```
a=1; b=5
for (( i=a ; i<b ; i++ )); do
    printf "$i,";
done;
printf "$b\n"
```

Comment: In case of variables I think a good way shall be: `a=1;b=5; seq --separator="," $a $b`

Answer (score 6):

Try to use:

```
seq --separator="," 1 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using numerical brace expansion, the only spaces that will ever appear are the ones between numbers, so you could post-process the result:

```
output=$(echo {1..5} | tr ' ' ',')
```

or

```
output=$(echo {1..5} | sed 's/ /,/g')
```

Answer (score 4):

This is more to further expand on expansion than to provide a practical solution: what follows is less concise and efficient than the alternatives proposed in other answers.

In Bash, the Internal Field Separator (`IFS`) is not used for brace expansion—hence, `IFS=","; echo {1..5}` won't work as you would like. It is used, however, when expanding a few other things, including:

#### Positional parameters

About the expansion of the special parameter `*`, quoting `man bash`:

> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.

We can use a function to exemplify:

```bsh
$ function fnc () {
>   IFS=','
>   printf '%s\n' "$*"
> }
$ fnc {1..5}
1,2,3,4,5
```

Note that this function also sets the value of `IFS` for the calling environment. This can be avoided in a portable way by enclosing the function body in parentheses (i.e. `fnc () ( IFS=... )`), with the side effect of having it executed in a subshell, or using `local IFS=,` to declare a variable which is local to the function (the `local` builtin is not specified in POSIX, but is available in several shells), or setting `IFS` back to its original value before the end of the function.

#### Arrays

When accessing the items of an array using the `*` subscript, again, quoting `man bash`:

> If the word is double-quoted, `${name[*]}` expands to a single word  with  the  value  of  each  array member separated by the first character of the IFS special variable, ...

Example (again, don't forget to set `IFS` back to a proper value):

```bsh
$ arr=( {1..5} )    # Populate an array with brace expansion and compound assignment
$ IFS=','
$ echo "${arr[*]}"  # Reference all the items with the * subscript
1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 3):

If you allow for spaces along with commas, try

```
$ echo {1..5},
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```